# Preserving depth when rendering in multipe layers (Cycles)

Tags: cycles-render-engine, compositing-nodes

I don't even know how to ask this question  and I a noob to blender.

I wanted to create a plasma canon

I created 3 render layers and Added them on top of each other...

For now this looks pretty good

Gun Front
[image: Front]

Compositing tree
[image: tree]

But then I tried to look at the gun from the back.... the bullet gets put in top of the gun. Is there any (easy) way to have the layers retain Z order?

Gun view back (bad)
[image: back]

Comment: Great question! Compositing is an oft-overlooked feature, especially using Cycles.

Comment: When I discovered it. a whole new world opened... (It took me 3 days to find out this feature even existed) I only joined after cycles got implemented, I am still feel like a noob. Maybe you know of a way to get this effect without compositing? I tried but with nodes and materials alone I could not do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yeah no problem,

On the flame render layers layer settings, under the Layer: blocks, there's a Mask Layer:   set of blocks.   Just select the corresponding layer for the cannon (so you're applying the cannon as a mask to the flame)

[image: layer setup]

Below is an example using a cube and a sphere, the sphere occluding and masking the cube.

[image: mask setup]

The Cubes' render layer output

[image: cube masked]

Comment: I thank you so much... it works great... I am still in the progress of making the gun and can't post new pictures right now (Read: I screwed it up a bit) I will post them in the next week so, so everyone can see.

Comment: hey great, I'm glad it worked out.  Good luck with the project, look forward to seeing the finished product.